# Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm trying to find a closed form for this integral:$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-x}dx$$

Here's the integrand graph:

[image]

Clearly it is convergent. My attempt is to obtain a closed form for the area under the curve. Is this possible?

Comment: That depends on your notion of *closed form*. Is $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^n}$$ considered as a *closed form*?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio No, that is most certainly not closed-form. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression

Comment: Then I guess it is not possible, but numerically your integral is extremely close to $2$.

Comment: You could consider it a constant. Otherwise $\pi$ would not be closed form as all methods to calculate it are non-finite series expansions.

Comment: @mathreadler If one took finitely many elementary functions and their inverses with rational arguments, one could make $\pi$ using trig.

Comment: Jack's first answer is probably the nearest you will get ... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream

Comment: @Donald observe that this is a different case because the range of integration is different.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: indeed this is not the classical *sophomore's dream* problem but it boils down to a series similar to $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^n}$ by splitting the integration range as $(0,1)\cup[1,+\infty)$ and applying simple manipulations.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out ... I had assumed it was just the classic Sophomore's dream ... there is a bit more to it.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt so which functions are considered elementary? Certainly if you consider trig and their inverses elementary you can express $\pi$ on closed form, but then you get away by design. If I consider a function more closely related to the constant I want to express as elementary then I would get away saying it has a closed form.

Comment: @mathreadler Generally, [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) refers to algebraic functions, exponential functions, trig functions, and their inverses.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Yes I know they are often considered to be, but I don't know why they are natural to consider elementary while so many other non-algebraic functions are not.

Comment: @mathreadler And your point here...?

Comment: It was more of a curious question than a point.

Comment: We have $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{-x}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^n}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+W(x))e^x}$$ with $W$ being Lambert's function.

Comment: $e^{-x} = 1/(e^{-x\log(x)})$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that you will be able to find a closed-form expression for your integral. Two special variants of your integral, however, are rather infamous as the ["Sophomore's Dream"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SophomoresDream.html) integrals. They are the integrals
$$\int_0^1 x^{x} dx$$
and
$$\int_0^1 x^{-x} dx$$
And, as of yet, no closed-form has been obtained for either of them. However, your integral
$$\int_0^\infty x^{-x} dx$$
Converges *incredibly* quickly, even more so than an exponential function, and so a very good approximation can be obtained rather quickly. Wolfram Alpha yields the approximation
$$\int_0^\infty x^{-x} dx\approx 1.99545595750014...$$
And so $2$ should be a good enough approximation. Even the [inverse symbolic calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard) doesn't yield anything for the approximation given by WA, so I doubt that it has any kind of closed form using the elementary functions or any other known constants.

Comment: One can approximate the remainder to a further extent by using the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), which quickly relates the given integral to Sophomore's dream.

Comment: Strange that it's so close to 2.

Comment: Not really that strange when you consider how many of these simple-looking integrals it's possible to construct by defining arbitrary operations like tetration. Some of them are bound to be close to integers. As best as I can tell, there's no real physical significance of $x^{-x}$ or of this integral.

Answer (score 4):

We have the following approximation:

Let $S$ be one of the Sophomore's dreams:

$$S=\int_0^1x^{-x}~\mathrm dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}$$

Then we have the integral $I$ in question,

$$I=\int_0^\infty x^{-x}~\mathrm dx=S+\int_1^\infty x^{-x}~\mathrm dx$$

The second integral has a quick trapezoidal sum approximation:

$$\int_1^\infty x^{-x}~\mathrm dx\approx-\frac12+\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}$$

Thus, we have

$$I\approx2S-\frac12=2.08257$$

The error is approximately $0.08711$

Answer (score 0):

$\int\limits_0^\infty x^{-x}dx=\int\limits_0^1 x^{-x}dx+\int\limits_0^1 x^{-2+1/x}dx$

The second integral is unpleasant to develope into a series.

But if we can use the solution $\,z_0\,$ for $\,\int\limits_0^1 (x^{xz} - x^{-2+1/x})dx=0$

with $\,z=z_0\approx 1.45354007846425$ , then we get:

$$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\infty x^{-x}dx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1+(-z_0)^{n-1}}{n^n}$$